# Delete Google full text search old index

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

Is there any way to delete google full text search index file from google cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't currently delete indexes, BUT you can delete the documents from it. So essentially, you will have an empty index. Whenever you need to use Full Text Search API again, recycle the index and you will be ok.

For details - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/lesson2

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deleted indexes by hand in http://localhost:8000/search/index?index=

I wonder how to do it automatically.